# Servers in Farm: Upgrade Required

Tags: 2013, central-administration, upgrade, stsadm

I am trying to clean up issues on SharePoint 2013.  My Farm is an in place 2010 to 2013 upgrade.  In Central Admin under "Servers in Farm" `(/_admin/FarmServers.aspx)` my Server is reporting that I have to do an upgrade.  However, clicking on "Upgrade Required" doesn't get me anywhere.

I went into PowerShell and ran this command: "`stsadm.exe -o localupgradestatus`".
I got the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for 'Microsoft.SharePoint.StsAdmin.SPStsAdmin' threw an
>   exception. ---> System.Bad ImageFormatException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its d ependencies. This
>   assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime
>   and cannot be loaded. File name: 'Microsoft.SharePoint,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.StsAdmin.SPStsAdmin..cctor()

I ran the "`Configuration Wizard`" and reran the PowerShell command, I still get the same error.

Any Idea how to fix this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the following..central admin > upgrade and migration > Review database status...on this page see if any database complaining about it?

Comment: also try to run the get-spproduct -local

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 inplace upgrade is not supported. I'd try to carve out a separate server for the time being in order to install SharePoint 2013 and pull over your content databases after you create a farm.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617150.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396